# Retrofit and Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to make a REST Client with Android and I read about retrofit. When I do some requests with retrofit even if the activity is destroyed the callback is executed.

How can I stop receiving the response after the activity is being destroyed?

```
apiService.getDummieContent().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assign the request to a variable and cancel it on activity destroy:

```
Call<ReponseBody> call = apiService.getDummieContent();
call.enqueue(...);

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    call.cancel();
}
```

Comment: if i am doing some staff onResponse method call.cancel will not force cancel the callback

Answer (score 1):

You can declare global variable apiService

```
Call<ReponseBody> apiService;
```

and then call api method for instance here **getDummieContent()**.Moreover you can manually check for the if call is **cancelled** in **OnFaliure** method. As in my case i was disabling swipeRefreshLayout which was getting null context on DestroyView because onFailure method was only called when view was destroyed, so with the help of this condition i always checked whether it is cancelled after on destroyed hence preventing exception.

```
apiService.getDummieContent().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

   @Override
   public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) 
   {

     // Do stuff here

   }

  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

  t.printStackTrace();

  if(call.isCanceled())
   {
      Log.e("isCanceled", " isCanceled");// check if it is cancelled on OnDestroy

   }

}

});
```

and in on destory **onDestroy**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    call.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Karan. Will `onFailure` always be called after `call.cancel()` was called? 
I tried finding some documentation on this to no avail unfortunately.